# expression for ParameterDateTime Format in SSRS 2008

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need an expression, to display the parameter,Date picker in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, kindly help me to do this,

i have tried with the expression,
                  =FormatDateTime(Parameter!Date.Value,"dd/mm/yyyy")

but, the above code doesn't display the date picker in the required format("dd/mm/yyyy").

kidly help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter date picker's format is based on the language of the browser, or you can hardcode it in the reportserver website.

for more information see http://geekswithblogs.net/naijacoder/archive/2008/06/26/123422.aspx